# How do I use cloud dataprep to convert my excel file to target formet regularly?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I'd like to convert my excel to proper format using Google Cloud Dataprep. How do I save my convert flow and use it as a template? For example, if there were two excel files named A and B and I create a flow to merge these two, next time there are two other files named C.xlsx and D.xlsx, how can I use the flow I created to merge C and D?

Answer (score 0):

You can [copy and reuse recipes](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Reuse-Recipe_136155028#reuse-copy-of-recipe-in-the-same-flow) (using the right-click or `...` context menus and selecting `Make a copy > Without inputs`), or you can [swap the input dataset](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Change-Dataset-Dialog_57344908) for the original recipe and select your new file without having to recreate the recipe.

If your goal is *automation*, this is a bit more difficult when your source is an Excel file (as these are only an allowed format [when using the uploader](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Import-Excel-Data_57344579)).

If you're able to have the data output in a CSV and uploaded to Cloud Storage, it opens up additional opportunities to [schedule](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Schedule-a-Job_118228655) and [parameterize](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Create-Dataset-with-Parameters_118228628) your process.